# SQL paramaterisation in C#, using SQL declared variables

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-insert

I have the following SQL query which I am sending from a C# program:

```
DECLARE @id as int
SELECT @id = max(fault_catagory_ident) FROM fault_catagory_list
INSERT INTO fault_catagory_list (fault_catagory_ident, fault_catagory)
VALUES (@id + 1, 'TEST')
SELECT @id + 1
```

The 'fault_catagory' value is coming from my program, but the ident value needs to be the next number in line (primary key) from the existing table in the database. My C# code is parameterising values for security.

I have two problems:

1. How can I get the @id + 1 value returned to my program (executeNonQuery doesn't return anything)?
2. How can I get @id as a parametarised value for the insert command?

I am wondering if my primary key could be automated in some way?

I want to carry all this out in one single query, as there will be a risk of multiple logins running this same query. If any happened to run simultainiously, the @id value may get duplicated and one would fail.

Apologies if there isn't enough info here, I'm on a learning curve!

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for `IDENTITY()` functionality

Comment: Don't use such code, ever. It *guarantees* duplicate values. It's completely unnecessary too. You can create a column with an `IDENTITY` constraint to have the database generate unique values

Comment: You can easily write a single `INSERT` and return any generated values with the `OUTPUT` clause. Add the `IDENTITY` constraint to `fault_catagory_ident` and use 
 `INSERT INTO fault_catagory_list (fault_catagory) OUTPUT inserted.fault_catagory_ident VALUES ('TEST')` to retrieve the generated value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you will find everything you need in this example provided in MSDN:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

in short:

1. to return a single parameter from a query ull use ExecuteScalar()
2. parameters are added to a query through the SqlCommand class provided in System.Data.SqlClient.

cheers!

Comment: Thanks, this should certainly help with returning the value I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice, think I have found the solution...
Firstly I need to recreate the table with the primary key column using the IDENTITY constraint (makes sense to use this now I know it exists!). Found a guide here (though it will mean some rebuilding of primary/foreign key links) https://www.datameer.com/blog/how-to-add-an-identity-to-an-existing-column-in-sql/

Then in C# program, use SqlCommand.executeScalar to return the identity value

```
Int identReturn = 0;
identReturn = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Thanks again for the responses.

Answer (score -1):

While I don't agree with the logic in which you are choosing identity row values for the inserted rows, you could certainly acheive that using `IDENTITY()` column attribute in the SQL table definition.

In case you have multiple SELECTs in your SQL command,
everytime you have a SELECT in your sql command, a new table is added to the passed in dataset to the data adapter.

```
string sql = "
   DECLARE @id as int
   SELECT @id = max(fault_catagory_ident) FROM fault_catagory_list
   INSERT INTO fault_catagory_list (fault_catagory_ident, fault_catagory)
   VALUES (@id + 1, 'TEST')
   SELECT @id + 1";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn); // assuming you already set connection
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds);

Console.WriteLine( ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);  // this will print @id
Console.WriteLine( ds.Tables[1].Rows[0][0]);  // this will print @id + 1
```

Comment: That's not a single query, but there's only a single result set. `SELECT @id`-...` sets the variable, it doesn't return anything. `cmd.ExecuteScalar` would return the incremented ID. A bigger problem though is that this code will generate duplicate values